# Retain point in magit while staging hunk by hunk?

Tags: magit, point

I am trying to stage few hunks of a file using magit.

My point is on first hunk like this

[image]

Now if I press `s` to stage this hunk, it will stage hunk and **moves point back to file** like this

[image]

Now to stage next hunk, again I have to **move point to hunk** and press `s`.

Instead of this, if magit can retain point position, it will be much easier for me to stage hunks very easily.

If I remember correctly old magit versions (1.x) had this desired behavior? How can I get back that behavior?

Comment: There's no option to enable this behavior, Magit should just always do that. Please open a feature request instead. Or really, you can also just wait a day or two - this should be easy, and I probably won't forget to do it.

Comment: @tarsius  Post bug fix as answer?

Comment: It's probably best to just delete this issue. (Do I actually have to mention your name or are you notified even if I don't do that?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magit should always do  that by default.

There was a bug in `magit` and it was fixed [in this commit](https://github.com/magit/magit/commit/0c2d2af79b5e42b27de99c4e927a29b87b6932cb) by  @tarsius